# Display value in label using values in different table in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am looking to display Hole_Num value from my Holes class, in my RoundDetails class within the RoundDetails/Create razor view.

Here is my Holes class:

public partial class Hole
    {
        public Hole()
        {
            this.RoundDetails = new HashSet();
        }

```
    public int HoleId { get; set; }
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public int TeeTypeId { get; set; }
    public int Hole_Num { get; set; }
    public int Yardage { get; set; }
    public byte Par { get; set; }
    public short Handicap { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RoundDetail> RoundDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual TeeType TeeType { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my RoundDetails class:

public partial class RoundDetail
    {
        public int RoundId { get; set; }
        public int GolferId { get; set; }
        public int FacilityId { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
        public int TeeTypeId { get; set; }
        public int HoleId { get; set; }
        public decimal Differential { get; set; }
        public Nullable Date { get; set; }
        public byte Score { get; set; }
        public Nullable Putts { get; set; }
        public Nullable GIR { get; set; }
        public Nullable FIR { get; set; }
        public Nullable Up_And_Down { get; set; }
        public Nullable Par_Save { get; set; }
        public Nullable Sand_Save { get; set; }
        public Nullable Driving_Distince { get; set; }
        public Nullable Proximity { get; set; }
        public Nullable Green_Fee { get; set; }

```
    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Facility Facility { get; set; }
    public virtual Golfer Golfer { get; set; }
    public virtual Hole Hole { get; set; }
    public virtual TeeType TeeType { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my razor view:

```
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Hole.Par)

                    </td>
```

How am I able to populate this label with the Par information from the Holes table?  I assume that some manipulation with the Create method of the RoundDetailController or creating a ViewModel of some sort is the way to go but I"m not sure which one or how start either.  Please help!